# Postgres: How to get row number when ordered by the result of operation?

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-number

Let us assume there is a table ‘items’ that has three columns: ‘id’, ‘pos’ and ‘neg’, and the result of selection should be ordered by the result of operation `pos - neg`.

So, the following is supposed to work:

```
SELECT
    id,
    pos - neg AS diff
FROM items
ORDER BY diff DESC
```

Now I need to get position of a specific row (in table) ordering the result by 'diff'. I tried this:

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT
        i.id,
        i.pos - i.neg AS diff,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY diff) AS position
    FROM items i)
SELECT s.*  FROM summary s WHERE s.id = 351435254
```

but the execution returns ERROR: column "diff" does not exist.

So, is it possible to get the position, or it would be better to keep diffs in a separate column?

Comment: diff is an alias try `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY i.pos - i.neg) AS position` instead

Comment: @Richard that works! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT
        i.id,
        i.pos - i.neg AS diff,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (i.pos - i.neg)) AS position
    FROM items i)
SELECT s.*  FROM summary s WHERE s.id = 351435254
```

Comment: That works, thanks! Somehow I didn't even think of it because in fact I have more complex calculation than 'pos - neg'…

Answer (score 3):

To avoid repeating the calculation, just move the `ROW_NUMBER()` to the outer query...

```
WITH summary AS (
    SELECT
        i.id,
        i.pos - i.neg AS diff       
    FROM
        items i
)
SELECT
    s.*,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.diff) AS position
FROM
    summary s
WHERE
    s.id = 351435254
```

During the inner query, references to `diff` will be scope limited to what existed *before* the `SELECT`, otherwise you can get circular references.

By the time of the outer query your new field `diff` exists, and so can be supplied as a parameter to other calculations, functions, etc.

Comment: Thank you! But I forgot to say that I need the position of a row inside the whole table, not the selection…

Comment: Same approach, have three levels of nested query. Inner most calculates diff, next level calculates position, next level applies the where clause.  That's expensive though, the whole table will need calculating and sorting...